# Adding Initial Condition to Custom Simulink discrete time integrator block

Tags: simulink

I'm trying to add an initial value condition to my custom trapezoidal integrator, using a sample time of 0.02 seconds. However, I am not sure how to add an initial condition signal to my input which will only execute once.
Any help would be appreciated.

Screenshot of my Simulink Code

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial value for the output of the unit delay block is a block parameter, which can easily be changed by double-clicking on the block and editing the resulting dialog.

If you are wanting to set an initial value for the output of the whole integration method (i.e. for the signal labelled `custom` in the diagram above) then you need to (manually) calculate what the initial value of the unit delay needs to be to achieve that value, and enter that into the unit delay block.  Typically this can be written as an equation, so only needs to be done once.

Comment: My current input signal is a constant 1. Now imagine that my actual input is a current. Essentially I am calculating current used (Ah). Periodically, I save the calculated value to nonvolatile memory. Now assume that the system reboots. I now want to add that saved value as the initial condition to my accumulator so that I still have lifetime current used rather than having it reset to 0 every time the system is reboot. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I figured it out, by doing something like this: https://imgur.com/a/mxH3HI3

I'm slightly confused why I need to divide my initial value by 0.02 (my sample and step time) but I guess it kind of makes sense.